# AWK filter first and last row of given variable, discard the middle rows

Tags: unix, awk, filtering

I am trying to filter a file by selecting the first and last row of a given variable in a tab-delimited txt file using AWK.

Tab-delimited file looks like this:

```
1 apple  30
2 apple  35
3 apple  36
4 apple  20
5 pear   10
6 pear   30
7 pear   45
8 orange 16 

END
```

and I am trying to process this using awk, to only print the first and last rows of each variable in $2 (the fruit column in this example)

The file I actually have is ~ 35000 rows in length, and has 3000 unique variables in the column i'm  wanting to use as the filter (so in this above example col2)

I was thinking the approach would be to create an array of unique col2 values, (apple, pear, orange) and then using this array extract the first and last values from the larger file... but some advise on the nomenclature needed to select the first and last row per indexed variable would be greatly appreciated. :)

INPUT file given above, expected output would be

```
1 apple  30
4 apple  20
5 pear   10
7 pear   45
8 orange 16
```

the output needs to include  those with only one entry too (the orange in this case)

Comment: Is the file sorted on column2?

Comment: Hi, yes the file is sorted on column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '$2!=prev{if (pline){print pline;}print;}{prev=$2;pline=$0;}END{print pline;}' file | uniq
```

Print every time a new 2nd column line is encountered. While printing the new 2nd column line, if the prev line is  not empty, print that as well.  uniq is to remove the the duplicate lines which gets printed in case of single record present in between.

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if the same data appears as both the first and last line for a given key value or if the data contained blank or `0` lines (assuming you'd want those handled just like every other line, easily skipped if not):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 != prev2 {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print rec
    }
    beg = rec = $0
    prev2 = $2
    next
}
{ rec = beg ORS $0 }
END { print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 apple  30
4 apple  20
5 pear   10
7 pear   45
8 orange 16
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu awk, no need external program

```
awk '{if($0~/^[a-z0-9]/) a[NR]=$0} END{f=1;asort(a); for(;i++<NR;){split(a[i],b);if(b[2]==$2||f){$1=b[1];$2=b[2];$3=b[3];if(f){f=0;print}} else if(b[2]){print;print b[1],($2=b[2]),b[3]}} }' d
```